# How can I loop through json file and return it as HttpRespones in Django?

Tags: python, json, django, jsonresponse

I have a json file inside my static folder in my django project. I want to return on all the 'id', and 'title' of each data.

I have this data in my json file.

```
    {"results": [
        {"id": "1", "movie_title": "COCO","cast":["cast1","cast2"]},
        {"id": "2", "movie_title": "THOR","cast":["cast1","cast2"]},
        {"id": "3", "movie_title": "IRONMAN","cast":["cast1","cast2"]}]}
```

I have this code that return all data from json file.

```
    def polls(request):

        ROOT_FILE = STATIC_ROOT + '/polls/coming_soon.json'

        json_data = open(ROOT_FILE)
        json_load = json.load(json_data)

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(json_load))
```

I would like to get, for example, only some specific values like 'id', 'title'. But when I tried to foreach the results from json_load, It only returns the value of first item in file. Here's my code to that.

```
    for r in json_load['results']:
        return HttpResponse(r['id'] + r['movie_title')
```

But this code only return the first data like this:

```
   1 COCO
```

I wanted to return like this:

```
   1 COCO
   2 THOR
   3 IRONMAN
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A simple work around is to append it to a list.

```
json_data =  {"results": [
        {"id": "1", "movie_title": "COCO","cast":["cast1","cast2"]},
        {"id": "2", "movie_title": "THOR","cast":["cast1","cast2"]},
        {"id": "3", "movie_title": "IRONMAN","cast":["cast1","cast2"]}]}

list1 = list()
def function1():
        for r in json_data["results"]:
                list1.append(r['id'] + ' '+  r['movie_title'])

function1()

for i in list1:
        print(i)

# outputs

1 COCO
2 THOR
3 IRONMAN
```

Reason why you are getting only `1 COCO` is because you are returning only 1 query